# How can i record a canvas animation with a video?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video, frontend

I have a video (from webcam or just a video file) playing and i have a canvas element for some animations.
I would like to record the both elements and them save to a file.

My question is: is there any solution for this? I mean, can i put the video inside de canvas and record the canvas?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `drawImage` with a video element. You will need to repeatedly redraw it so the framerate may be less-than-desirable. You could also just position the canvas on top of the video.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderO'Mara, but i need to draw the video and the canvas together. The canvas will be above the video.

Comment: What kind of "record" are you talking about? Still images or another video stream?

Comment: @Philipp, another video stream.

Comment: That's a tricky one. AFAIK html5 can only *decode* videos and doesn't define a way to *encode* them like it can do for still-images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that by using [RecodRTC.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC) to record HTML/Canvas into webm format

Comment: Does it supports in macOS?

Comment: @UmeshPatadiya What you mean?

Comment: It works! I did it in 2015. Maybe it worth doing another research, it might have other solutions now.